# Лучшие практики вывода данных из MySQL в массив PHP (ООП)

Tags: php, mysql, ооп

В данный момент интересует вывод всех статей.

Для дальнейшей передачи в контроллер, и для выдачи вьюхи.

Примеры кода ,или где можно об этом больше узнать....

У меня есть класс с методами для получения массива.

```
class Db implements IDbAccess
{
protected $host = "localhost";
protected $login = "root";
protected $password = "root";
protected $dataBase = "devBlog";
protected $conn;

protected static $instance = null;

private function __construct(){}

private function __clone(){}

private function __wakeup(){}

public static function getInstance()
{
    if(is_null(self::$instance)){
        self::$instance = new static;
    }
    return self::$instance;

}


public function getConnection()
{
    if(is_null($this->conn)){
        $this->conn = new mysqli(

            $this->host,
            $this->login,
            $this->password,
            $this->dataBase
        );
    }
    if(!$this->conn){
        throw new DbException("Что-то пошло не так");
    }

    return $this->conn;
}


public function query($sql)
{
    return $this->getConnection()->query($sql);
}

public function fetchAll($sql)
{
    $res = $this->query($sql);

    return $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

public function fetchObject($sql, $class)
{
    $res = $this->query($sql);
    return $res->fetch_object($class);
}
}
```

Затем создаю дочерний класс:

```
class Article extends Model
{
public $article_id;
public $header;
public $content;
public $owner;
public $date;
public $login;
public $name;



public static function getAll()
{

    return self::getConnetcion()->fetchAll
    (
        "SELECT a.article_id, a.content, a.header, a.owner, a.date, users.name, users.login
        FROM devBlog.Articles a
        INNER JOIN devBlog.users ON a.owner = users.user_id;"
    );
}

/*
 *
 */
public static function getById($id)
{

    return self::getConnetcion()->fetchObject
    (
        "SELECT a.article_id, a.content, a.header, a.owner, a.date,   users.name, users.login
        FROM devBlog.Articles a
        INNER JOIN devBlog.users ON a.owner = users.user_id
        WHERE a.article_id = $id;", Article::class

    );

}


 public static function create(){

      return self::getConnetcion()->query
      (
          "INSERT INTO Articles (header, content, owner) 
          VALUE ('Some new text',\"a lot of new things\",2);"
      );
 }

 public static function update($id){

     return self::getConnetcion()->query(
         "UPDATE Articles SET header=\"xxx\", content=\"some text\",    owner =\"1\"
         WHERE article_id = $id;"
     );

 }

 public static function delete($id){

     return self::getConnetcion()->query(
         "DELETE FROM devBlog.Articles WHERE article_id = $id;"
     );

 }
}
```

Затем создаю объект класса в контроллере и "инкостылирую", остановился на этом, первый опыт не могу материала найти для дальнейшего вывода, либо просто по книге не дошёл до этого материала.

```
class ArticleController
 {
protected $templateRoot = "views";

protected $action;



public function run(){


    $method ='action' . ucfirst($this->action);

    $this->$method;


}

//вывести статьи
public function actionList(){

    $model = new Article();


    $articles = $model->getAll();


    $this->renderTemplate('articleList',['articles' => $articles]);
}

//вывести статьи по одиночке
public function actionArticleById(){

}
//удалить статью
public function actionDelete(){

}
//создать
public function actionCreate(){

}

//изменить статью
public function actionUpdate(){

}

protected function renderTemplate($name, $args =[]){
    extract($args);
    $templatePath = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/{$this->templateRoot}/{$name}.php";
    require "$templatePath";
}





public function setAction($action)
{
    $this->action = $action;

    return $this;
}



}
```

Контроллер так же использует template articleList.php для выдачи вьюхи в html.

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article):?>
<div>
    <h2>
        <a href="/index.php/?c=Article&a=Display&id=<?  =$article['article_id'] ?>">
            <?= $article['header'];?>
        </a>
    </h2 >
    <p><?=$article['content'];?></p >
</div >
```

Comment: Вопрос сильно общий. Так же вы не привели ни кусочка кода. В чем заключается проблема? http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php - отличная отправная точка. http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Comment: Так а проблема в чем? Пробежался по коду. Если игнорировать архетектурную часть, то похоже, что у вас все есть.

Comment: я всё понял=) проблема бала в пути